# Spring request mapping folders

Tags: spring, mapping

Respect,

I have some problems with request mapping with spring, now I use spring 4.1

I have 2 controllers in my application and I want handle request mapping in specific way.

In first controller I want handle all mapping folders
`@RequestMapping(value={"/", "/**"})`

In another controller I want also handle all sub folders of app/ folder
`@RequestMapping(value={"/app", "/app/**"})`

and this works good, but now I ca not access my src files css, images etc..
all this files are located in src/css/ folder.

How to solve this problem.
maybe I must create one more controller only for src folder
`@RequestMapping(value={"/src", "/src/**"})`

Answer (score 0):

Resources such as /css , /images, /js etc., are to be placed  under WEB-INF/resources
For eg. 
WEB-INF/resources/css
WEB-INF/resources/js

Pls try to rearrange to above structure...